# How can I tell, inside a controller, if it has been run from ng-controller or a route

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an AngularJS controller which is used both on a specific page, defined in a route:

```
when("/search/:term", {controller:'SearchCtrl',  templateUrl:'/static/templates/supersearch/list.html'});
```

and also attached to an element in the header, which is used on all pages:

```
<div ng-controller="SearchCtrl">
  <form class="navbar-form pull-left super-search">
    ...
  </form>
<div>
```

How can I tell, from within the controller, which context it is being run in?

Things I've tried:

**ng-init**

I tried using `<div ng-controller="SearchCtrl" ng-init="init(true)">` to tell the controller if it was running from the header search form, but it seems that `ng-init` is executed after the controller, so it doesn't have access to the passed parameter.

**Passing $element**

If I inject `$element` to the controller, I am able to access the DOM node that the `ng-controller` directive is attached to, however angular raises an error in the case of the page with the route, because there is no `$element` available to inject.

So I either need some way to pass a parameter to the controller, or some way to tell which context the controller is being run from (inline `ng-controller` vs. route). Thanks!

Comment: Out of curiosity, what logic do you have in place that should only be executed when triggered from a route but not explicitly  requested from within the view(or the other way around)?

Comment: Did you try injecting `$routeParams` in both cases?

Comment: @IvanKrechetov Hmm, `$routeParams` may just be something I can use to separate them yes, I'll try that and update.

Comment: @callmekatootie I have some different params I need to pass to my server-side depending on if it's the full page or the header search, and didn't want to create an almost duplicate controller for each case.

Comment: @IvanKrechetov Checking based on `$routeParams` did the trick, if you post an answer I'll mark it as accepted. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest distinguishing the cases using the injected `$routeParams` [service](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24routeParams) into the controller's function.

Answer (score 1):

The actual processing of the search must be done in the service layer. Not in the controller.
Also merging basically two controllers into one can lead to a whole host of problems.

Consider having two controllers. One for the full seach and one for the header search.
Both these controllers get the `Search` service injected which will handle the search.

```
app.controller('HeaderSeachController', function (Search) {
    Search.headerSearch();
});

app.controller('SeachController', function (Search) {
    Search.search();
});

app.service('Search', function () {
    return {
        headerSearch: function () { ... },
        search: function () { ... },
        _sharedLogic: function () { ... }
    };
});
```